# prove functions sin(t), cos(t), t are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

My approach is as follows.

> To show linear independency, I have to prove

$$a \sin(t)+b\cos(t)+c(t)=0 \iff a=b=c=0$$

$(\Leftarrow)$ easy

$(\Rightarrow)$

if $t=0, b=0$.

if $t=\pi/2, a+c\pi/2=0 $.

if $t=3\pi/2, a+3c\pi/2=0 $

so, $a=b=c=0$.

Did I prove it completely? In the proof to the right, I'm worried that I haven't shown that $(a, b, c)$ is ***unique*** as $(0, 0, 0)$.
If there exist something wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: It's OK but should complete the last two equations by subtracting thm, and get $2c\pi=0$ so that $c=0,$ then plug that into second (or third) equation.

Comment: Why don't I have to show uniqueness?

Comment: Is it because we need to find (a,b,c) that satisfies the linearly independent condition for **every t**?

Comment: You did show uniqueness. You always have the solution $(a, b, c) = (0, 0, 0)$, and what you showed is if $(a, b, c) = (a_0, b_0, c_0)$ is some solution (possibly the same as $(0, 0, 0)$, possibly different), then $(a_0, b_0, c_0) = (0, 0, 0)$ (i.e. definitely the same). This shows the solution to this equation is unique!

Comment: There's a sign error for $t=\dfrac{3\pi}2$: the equation should be $-a+\dfrac{3c\pi}2=0$.